# How can i retrieve data from a textarea using PHP?

Tags: php, forms

Given the following HTML form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="comments.php">
    <textarea name="text" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Update" />
</form>
```

...and the following PHP code (`comments.php`):

```
<?php
require("includes/config.php");
$fromtextarea = $_POST['text'];
$con = mysql_connect($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($dbname , $con);

$sql = "INSERT INTO textarea (comment) VALUES ('$fromtextarea')";
if (mysql_query($sql)) {
    header("Location: home.php");

}
else
    echo "no no no";
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

How can I get the data and display all user comments on a page?

Comment: Take a look at mysqli and dont use mysql_ statements those are deprecated. you must do a "select * from textarea" query the iterate over it

Comment: Means, You have multiple text area in page right..?

Comment: yes and then display these multiple text area in one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at SELECT sql statement. Your query should look like something like this:

```
SELECT comment FROM textarea;
```

Then see how to manipulate the result with mysql_fetch_* functions in PHP (http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

By the way, mysql_* functions are deprecated (and will be deleted soon). I advise you using mysqli_* functions (http://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.mysqli.php) or (better) PDO (http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score -1):

Do like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO textarea (comment) VALUES ('". $_POST["text"] . "')";
```

Make sure you sanitize it before using it in your query.

Comment: Example code will find its way into production code. And this is a **major** SQL injection vector, that you're posting here.

Comment: Ok, thats a new requirement. You;ll have to be more clear on tht.

Comment: Any PHP+MySQL tutorial should show how to do a query and display the results. SO is not a replacement for learning how to program.